# extract substrings using python regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I would like to use a regular expression that matches any text between two strings:

```
   sample_string= "Message ID: SM9MatRNTnMAYaylR0QgOH///qUUveBCbw==  
    2021-07-10T20:48:23.997Z john s (X Y Bank) -
    john.s@xy.com:  
     [EVENT] 347376954900491 (john.s@xy.com) created room
    (roomName='CSTest' roomDescription='CS Test Chat Room' COPY_DISABLED=false
    READ_ONLY=false DISCOVERABLE=false MEMBER_ADD_USER_ENABLED=false
    roomType=PRIVATE conversationScope=internal owningCompany=X Y
    Bank)
    
    Message ID: nsabNaqeXfuEj9mBEhvS0n///qUUveAhbw==  
    2021-07-10T20:48:23.997Z john s (X Y Bank) -
    john.s@xy.comsays  
     [EVENT] 347376954900491 (john.s@xy.com) invited 347376954900486
    (kerren.n@xy.com) to room (CSTest|john s|16091907435583)
    
    Message ID: Nu/EYTkTQ5qdbqzZ0Rig8n///qUUvQ42dA==  
    2021-07-10T20:48:23.997Z john s (X Y Bank) -
    john.s@xy.comsays  
    
    Catchyou later
    
      
    
    Message ID: dy2yaByqhm+n88Gd3VQOhH///qUUrz8odA==  
    2021-07-10T20:48:23.997Z kerren n (X Y Bank) -
    nancy.n@xy.comsays  
    
    KeywordContent_ Cricket is a bat-and-ball game played between two teams of
    eleven players on a field at the centre of which is a 20-metre (22-yard) pitch
    with a wicket at each end, each comprising two bails balanced on three stumps.
    The batting side scores runs by striking the ball bowled at the wicket with
    the bat, while the bowling and fielding side tries to prevent this and dismiss
    each player (so they are "out").
    
      
    
    * * *
    
    Generated by Content Export Service | Stream Type: SymphonyPost |
    Stream ID: ZZo5pRRPFC18uzlonFjya3///qUUveBHdA== | Room Type: Private |
    Conversation Scope: internal | Owning Company: X Y Bank | File
    Generated Date: 2021-07-10T20:48:23.997Z | Content Start Date:
    2021-07-10T20:48:23.997Z | Content Stop Date: 2021-07-10T20:48:23.997Z  
    
    * * *
    
    *** (780787) Disclaimer: 
    (incorporated in paris with Ref. No. ZC18, is authorised by Prudential Regulation
    Authority (PRA) and regulated by Financial Conduct Authority and PRA. oyp and
    its affiliates (We) monitor this confidential message meant for your
    information only. We make no recommendation or offer. You should get
    independent advice. We accept no liability for loss caused hereby. See market
    commentary disclaimers (
    http://wholesalebanking.com/en/utility/Pages/d-mkt.aspx ),
    Dodd-Frank and EMIR disclosures (
    http://wholesalebanking.com/en/capabilities/financialmarkets/Pages/default.aspx
    ) "
```

In this example, I would like to extract everything after `emailID` and keyword `Messaage ID:`
so expected output would be:

> ```
> extracted_list =[':  
>  [EVENT] 347376954900491 (john.s@xy.com) created room
> (roomName='CSTest' roomDescription='CS Test Chat Room' COPY_DISABLED=false
> READ_ONLY=false DISCOVERABLE=false MEMBER_ADD_USER_ENABLED=false
> roomType=PRIVATE conversationScope=internal owningCompany=X Y
> Bank)','says  
>  [EVENT] 347376954900491 (john.s@xy.com) invited 347376954900486
> (kerren.n@xy.com) to room (CSTest|john s|16091907435583)','says Catchyou later','says 
> KeywordContent_ Cricket is a bat-and-ball game played between two teams of
> eleven players on a field at the centre of which is a 20-metre (22-yard) pitch
> with a wicket at each end, each comprising two bails balanced on three stumps.
> The batting side scores runs by striking the ball bowled at the wicket with
> the bat, while the bowling and fielding side tries to prevent this and dismiss
> each player (so they are "out").']
> ```

**Note:** everything after *** at last is not the part of text

What I tried so far is:

```
text = re.findall(r'\S+@\S+\s+(.*)Message ID', sample_string)
print (text)
##output: []
```

Comment: So, basically your question is: How to extract a part of a text (string), starting from `emailID` up until `Messaage ID`? Always try to provide a minimal example, not a big wall of text.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger Yes, sorry I have just started to use this platform.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an `emailID` somewhere in there?

Comment: @Jesper emailID is right after `(X Y Bank) -`

Comment: I think you mean `[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\s(.*?)\bMessage ID\b` https://regex101.com/r/zd5w8v/1 But you have to add `re.DOTALL` as the last parameter of re.findall

Comment: I voted to close this question because the code sample is too long. Please [edit] your post to pare your code down to a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
(?s)\S+@\S+?((?:says?|:)?\s.*?)\s+(?:Message ID|\* +\* +\*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cmNaU1/3).

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - same as `re.DOTALL`, inline modifier to make `.` match across line breaks
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars (can be replaced with `[^\s@]+`)
- `@` - a `@` char
- `\S+?` - one or more non-whitespace chars as few as possible
- `((?:says?|:)?\s.*?)` - Group 1: an optional `says`/`say`/`:` and then a whitespace and then any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?:Message ID|\* +\* +\*)` - either `Message ID` or `* * *` like substring.